# How to merge 2 strings alternately in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string

I have 2 strings:

```
a = "qwer"

b = "asd"

Result = "qawsedr"
```

Same is the length of b is greater than a. show alternate the characters.

What is the best way to do this? Should I use loop?

Comment: you could use the answer from max and then concat the rest of the string left

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the chars from your `a` and `b` string to work with them as arrays and then "merge" them using `zip`, then `join` them.

In the case of strings with different length, the array values must be reversed, so:

```
def merge_alternately(a, b)
  a = a.chars
  b = b.chars
  if a.length >= b.length
    a.zip(b)
  else
    array = b.zip(a)
    array.map{|e| e != array[-1] ? e.reverse  : e}
  end
end

p merge_alternately('abc', 'def').join
# => "adbecf"
p merge_alternately('ab', 'zsd').join
# => "azbsd"
p merge_alternately('qwer', 'asd').join
# => "qawsedr"
```

Comment: Hmmm, try `a="ab"` `b="zsd"` it gives `azbs`. it needs to give `azbsd`

Comment: That's because of the length of values in the array, but you can check it before doing the `zip` step.

Comment: I've updated the answer, reversing the array values when the length of a is minor than b.

Comment: `a="abc"` `b="def"` results incorectly.

Comment: `a.split('')` is an antipattern; I wish I knew where people keep learning it. Do `a.chars` or, to get an Enumerator, `a.each_char`.

Comment: Thanks @JordanRunning, I didn't know it!

Comment: `a.length > b.length || a.length == b.length` is the same as `a.length >= b.length`. Also you don't need `flatten` (`[["a"],["b"]].join` returns the same as `["a","b"].join`) or `compact` (`["a",nil].join` returns `"a"`).

Comment: Yes, you're right @JordanRunning, that's great, I've updated the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sebastián's answer gets the job done, but it's needlessly complex. Here's an alternative:

```
def merge_alternately(a, b)
  len = [a.size, b.size].max
  Array.new(len) {|n| [ a[n], b[n] ] }.join
end
merge_alternately("ab", "zsd")
# => "azbsd"
```

The first line gets the size of the longer string. The second line uses the block form of the Array constructor; it yields the indexes from 0 to `len-1` to the block, resulting in an array like `[["a", "z"], ["b", "s"], [nil, "d"]]`. `join` turns it into a string, conveniently calling `to_s` on each item, which turns `nil` into `""`.

Here's another version that does basically the same thing, but skips the intermediate arrays:

```
def merge_alternately(a, b)
  len = [a.size, b.size].max
  len.times.reduce("") {|s, i| s + a[i].to_s + b[i].to_s }
end
```

`len.times` yields an Enumerator that yields the indexes from `0` to `len-1`. `reduce` starts with an empty string `s` and in each iteration appends the next characters from `a` and `b` (or `""`—`nil.to_s`—if a string runs out of characters).

You can see both on repl.it: https://repl.it/I6c8/1

Just for fun, here's a couple more solutions. This one works a lot like Sebastián's solution, but pads the first array of characters with `nil`s if it's shorter than the second:

```
def merge_alternately(a, b)
  a, b = a.chars, b.chars
  a[b.size - 1] = nil if a.size < b.size
  a.zip(b).join
end
```

And it wouldn't be a Ruby answer without a little `gsub`:

```
def merge_alternately2(a, b)
  if a.size < b.size
    b.gsub(/./) { a[$`.size].to_s + $& }
  else
    a.gsub(/./) { $& + b[$`.size].to_s }
  end
end
```

See these two on repl.it: https://repl.it/I6c8/2